# SQL Address Parsing

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I have a query where I'm parsing for unit # from some addresses.

```
CASE WHEN Address1 LIKE '%apt %' THEN SUBSTRING(Address1, CHARINDEX('Apt', Address1), LEN(Address1))
```

This works as it should when the address is set up as: "123 Main St. Apt. 1A".

I will get "Apt. 1A" as my result.

However, there are some instances where my data is set up differntly, an example of this would be "Apt. 2B 123 Fake Street". When the data is set up like this I get "Apt. 2B 123 Fake Street"

The result I'm looking for is "Apt. 2B"

How do I get my query to get the "Apt." text and all of the following text up to the next space?

Comment: Parsing addresses in TSQL doesn't seem a good idea.

Answer (score 2):

There's a ton of things that could make this go wrong... and this code probably won't work for all cases depending on the format of your address. Assuming the format is `Apt` then a space `AptNumberLetter` then a space... this could work. I broke it up to show what it does. Again, normalizing dates is what you need to do as Martin stated.

```
declare @table table (addy varchar(450))
insert into @table
values
('Apt. 2B 123 Fake Street'),
('123 Main St. Apt. 1A')

select
    addy
    ,CHARINDEX('Apt',addy)startLocation
    ,CHARINDEX(' ',addy,CHARINDEX('Apt',addy)) firstSpace
    ,CHARINDEX(' ',addy,CHARINDEX(' ',addy,CHARINDEX('Apt',addy)) + 1) endSpace
    ,substring(addy,CHARINDEX('Apt',addy),case when CHARINDEX(' ',addy,CHARINDEX(' ',addy,CHARINDEX('Apt',addy)) + 1) = 0 then 99 else CHARINDEX(' ',addy,CHARINDEX(' ',addy,CHARINDEX('Apt',addy)) + 1) end) FinalResult
from @table
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are open to a UDF.

Tiered of parsing and extracting strings (charindex,left,right,...), I modified a parse/split udf to accept two non-like parameters.

Now, parsing addresses can be a slippery-slope.  See my answer here [Address standardization within a database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41249742/address-standardization-within-a-database/41249971#41249971)

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable table (Address1 varchar(450))
Insert into @YourTable values 
 ('Apt. 2B 123 Fake Street')
,('123 Main St. Apt. 1A')
,('100 North Main St.')

Select A.Address1
      ,Apt = 'Apt. '+B.RetVal
 From @YourTable A
 Outer Apply [dbo].[udf-Str-Extract](' '+A.Address1+' ',' Apt. ',' ') B
```

**Returns**

```
Address1                     Apt
Apt. 2B 123 Fake Street      Apt. 2B
123 Main St. Apt. 1A         Apt. 1A
100 North Main St.           NULL
```

**The UDF if Interested**

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[udf-Str-Extract] (@String varchar(max),@Delimiter1 varchar(100),@Delimiter2 varchar(100))
Returns Table 
As
Return (  

with   cte1(N)   As (Select 1 From (Values(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) N(N)),
       cte2(N)   As (Select Top (IsNull(DataLength(@String),0)) Row_Number() over (Order By (Select NULL)) From (Select N=1 From cte1 N1,cte1 N2,cte1 N3,cte1 N4,cte1 N5,cte1 N6) A ),
       cte3(N)   As (Select 1 Union All Select t.N+DataLength(@Delimiter1) From cte2 t Where Substring(@String,t.N,DataLength(@Delimiter1)) = @Delimiter1),
       cte4(N,L) As (Select S.N,IsNull(NullIf(CharIndex(@Delimiter1,@String,s.N),0)-S.N,8000) From cte3 S)

Select RetSeq = Row_Number() over (Order By N)
      ,RetPos = N
      ,RetVal = left(RetVal,charindex(@Delimiter2,RetVal)-1) 
 From  (
        Select *,RetVal = Substring(@String, N, L) 
         From  cte4
       ) A
 Where charindex(@Delimiter2,RetVal)>1

)
/*
Max Length of String 1MM characters

Declare @String varchar(max) = 'Dear [[FirstName]] [[LastName]], ...'
Select * From [dbo].[udf-Str-Extract] (@String,'[[',']]')
*/
```

Comment: Is there a code golf version of this somewhere?  (Remind me never to go up against you in a SQL coding event)

Comment: @xQbert I'd partner-up with you any day.  Just a lazy coder.  I'd rather write one function and use in numerous times.

Comment: i'm going to save this for later

Comment: @scsimon Honestly, I like this one.  I've used it for parsing JSON, XML, HTML, and numerous miscellanous others.