# How to split string to takeout a specific part in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, t-sql, split

I have a situation where I want to split address into `Street Number` and `Street Name`.

**Sample Data**

- **1093** Hundred Line Road
- **Flat 4442** Holly StreetAvondale
- **Apartment 1401/142** Shakespeare Road
- **Unit K109 Northbridge 45** Akoranga Drive, Northcote

In these examples, the bold part is `Street Number` and rest is `Street Name`.

My current effort is not helping me so far. Any one got a quick solution to that?

-Key is the `Street Number` part of the address ends where the last occurrence of **Number** ends.

Comment: Does your data always consist of Streen Number? Does it always end in a number?

Comment: What are you going to do for 1200 5th St (resulting in `th St`) or 400 Main St PO Box 123 Springfield PA (`Springfield PA`)?

Comment: For 5th.... the whole word should work.  Not doing Post Box Addresses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable Table ([Id] varchar(50),[Addr] varchar(50))
Insert Into @YourTable Values 
 (1,'1093 Hundred Line Road')
,(2,'Flat 4442 Holly StreetAvondale')
,(3,'Apartment 1401/142 Shakespeare Road')
,(4,'Unit K109 Northbridge 45 Akoranga Drive, Northcote')

Select ID 
      ,Addr1 = left(Addr,len(Addr)-patindex('%[0-9]%',reverse(Addr))+1)
      ,Addr2 = ltrim(right(Addr,patindex('%[0-9]%',reverse(Addr))-1))
 From @YourTable
```

**Or Just for Fun - Using a Cross Apply**

```
Select ID 
      ,Addr1 = substring(Addr,1,B.Pos)
      ,Addr2 = ltrim(substring(Addr,B.Pos+1,100))
 From @YourTable
 Cross Apply (values (len(Addr)-patindex('%[0-9]%',reverse(Addr))+1)) B(Pos)
```

**Returns**

```
ID  Addr1                       Addr2
1   1093                        Hundred Line Road
2   Flat 4442                   Holly StreetAvondale
3   Apartment 1401/142          Shakespeare Road
4   Unit K109 Northbridge 45    Akoranga Drive, Northcote
```

**I should note:**

Parsing an address can be a slippery slope.  Consider the following:  [Address standardization within a database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41249742/address-standardization-within-a-database/41249971#41249971)

Comment: Thanks, John. Agreed with standardization but data coming from 7 different systems with 30 yr+ old records and 70k plus clients. Everything is split in Address1Line1, Address1Line2, Address1Line3, Address1Line4, PostCode1, City1, Suburb1, Country1 and for N number of addresses..yet data entry issues cause stupid problems.

Comment: Thanks, John. Upvoted for effort. Verifying the results atm. :)

Comment: @Viking Happy to help

Comment: My examples were not rich enough with the new address patterns that I just figured out but I'm okay to work from here onward. Both @vkp and John's answers are *almost* correct for given samples but marking John's reply as the marked answer for more details. Hope vkp is okay with that, please?

Answer (score 4):

If the pattern of strings is consistent, you can use

```
select 
ltrim(rtrim(reverse(substring(reverse(address),patindex('%[0-9]%',reverse(address)),len(address))))) as streetNum,
ltrim(rtrim(reverse(substring(reverse(address),1,patindex('%[0-9]%',reverse(address))-1)))) as streetName
from tbl
```

Find the occurrence of first number in the reversed string using `patindex` and use `substring` and `reverse` to split them into separate fields.

Comment: Thanks, vkp. Upvoted for the effort. Verifying the results atm. :)

Comment: My examples were not rich enough with the new address patterns that I just figured out but I'm okay to work from here onward. Both @vkp and John's answers are *almost* correct for given samples but marking John's reply as the marked answer for more details. Hope vkp is okay with that, please?

Answer (score 1):

Another option...

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Address', 'U') IS NOT NULL 
DROP TABLE #Address;

CREATE TABLE #Address (
    StreetAddress VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL 
    );
INSERT #Address (StreetAddress) VALUES
    ('1093 Hundred Line Road'),
    ('Flat 4442 Holly StreetAvondale'),
    ('Apartment 1401/142 Shakespeare Road'),
    ('Unit K109 Northbridge 45 Akoranga Drive, Northcote');

--  SELECT * FROM #Address a;

--========================================================

SELECT 
    *,
    StreetNum = LEFT(a.StreetAddress, sl.SplitLocation),
    StreetName = SUBSTRING(a.StreetAddress, sl.SplitLocation + 1, 50)
FROM
    #Address a
    CROSS APPLY ( VALUES (PATINDEX('%[^0-9] [0-9]%', REVERSE(a.StreetAddress))) ) rs (ReverseSplit)
    CROSS APPLY ( VALUES (LEN(a.StreetAddress) - rs.ReverseSplit) ) sl (SplitLocation);
```

HTH, Jason

Comment: Thanks, Jason. Upvoted for effort. Verifying the results though :)