# Matching addresses using fuzzy logic

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables of addresses that I am trying to match to. Both are structured with Street (including number), city, state and zipcode.  In my query, I am trying to join the two tables Like this:

```
JOIN [AxSupport].[dbo].Address ADR ON LPA.City = ADR.City 
   and LPA.State = ADR.State 
   and ADR.ZipCode = LPA.ZIPCODE 
   and ADR.COUNTRY = LPA.COUNTRY
   and ADR.Street  = LPA.STREET
```

I tested with one customer that has 2020 address records records and the joined result only returns 79 records.  If I change the street comparison to Soundex(ADR.Street) = SoundEx(LPA.Street) I get 2660 records.  Is there another way of formatting the streets to get an accurate return?

Comment: The values are not the same. For example, `St` is not the same as `Street`. If you need to compare this way, you need to normalize your addresses.

Comment: This is a tricky business requirement. You have to decide what is a match for your requirements, and then post some sample data to obtain help with making the match.

Comment: Address matching is a slippery slope.  Normalization is the way to go here.  You would be surprised on the variations of Boulevard alone.  Take a peek at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41249742/address-standardization-within-a-database/41249971#41249971

Comment: Normalisation is best, but next best is probably a lookup table of abbreviations/misspellings.

Comment: I sort of agree with John, but the terminology is "standardization".  You need to standardize the addresses -- and you can find vendors of such software or services on the web.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your responses.  I'm going to work with the AR team to see what we can do to clean these up.