# SQL Replace Issues

Tags: sql, sql-server

Good Day All -

Trying to use the replace function to clean up some address issues during data extract.

The issue I'm running into is I only want to update the address if the street type is abbreviated.

Address 1 needs to be updated so 'Ci' becomes 'Circle', but I don't want address 2 to end up with 'Circlercle'.

1. 187624 W Windor Ci
2. 187624 W Windor Circle

```
select replace(address, ' Ci', ' Circle')  as address
```

At times the 'Ci' value are the last characters in the field or they can be followed by and apartment number.  I tried using ' Ci ' for the find, but still missing addresses if the address field ends with ' Ci'.

Any thoughts much appreciated.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a case expression to make `replace` apply to only relevant records

```
select case when address like '% Ci%' and address not like '% Circle%' 
            then replace(address, ' Ci', ' Circle')
            else address end  as address
```

You can also use a nested replace assuming resulting "Circlercle" is not a legitimate address suffix

```
select replace(replace(address, ' Ci', ' Circle'),'Circlercle','Circle') as address
```

Comment: Thank you for the response.  I did consider the second example you proveded, but figured it could get a bit cumbersom as I'm going to have to replace multiple street types.  Is there a limit on nested replace statements?

Comment: @Chelle It might depend on the db, but I want to say 32 for SQL Server. If you have  a few more street types to consider, you'd be better off with the case expression. Just add additional `when` to additional street types. If it's way too many, you could build a lookup table with a few columns that specify what needs to be matched, what doesn't, and what the replacement should be. Then you just join to that table and use only one replace

Answer (score 0):

Normalizing an address is trickier that one may think.  Perhaps take a peek at [Address standardization within a database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41249742/address-standardization-within-a-database/41249971#41249971)

If open to a UDF, you can perform MULTPLE replaces as defined by a table.  The following example can be converted into a function and I would suggest the table variable be an actual table.

**Example**

```
Declare @S varchar(max) = '123 NW Bvd.'

Declare @Map table (strFrom varchar(50),strTo varchar(100))
Insert Into @Map values
 ('NW'   ,'Northwest')
,('Blvd' ,'Boulevard')
,('Bvd'  ,'Boulevard')
,('Bvd.' ,'Boulevard')
-- Add as many as needed

Set @S=' '+@S+' '

Select @S=replace(@S,' '+strFrom+' ',' '+strTo+' ')
 From  (Select top 1000 * 
         From  @Map 
         Order By len(strFrom) desc
       ) A
 Order By len(strFrom) desc
```

**Returns**

```
123 Northwest Boulevard
```

Comment: Thank you for your response John!  I was able to use the replace function to get what I needed, but this seems more elegant.  Going to try to employ in my script and if anything at least I'll get some practice :)

Comment: @Chelle Always happy to help.  To be perfectly honest, this approach is far more robust than having to maintain code.