# Isolate Number from Address String in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am doing a piece of work that involves standardizing address formats for my company and I was wondering if it was possible to isolate the housing/apartment number of a dwelling in a string in SQL Server. The data quality is currently poor and therefore address standardization is not good.

Some examples below; with desired outcome

| Dwelling Address | Outcome Desired |
| --- | --- |
| Flat 123 Fake Street | 123 |
| 48 Bond Street | 48 |
| Apartment 234 Lemon Lane | 234 |

Any code examples would be greatly appreciated.

Many thanks.

Comment: This should help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16667251/query-to-get-only-numbers-from-a-string

Comment: What happens if you have "Flat 1 12 Long Street"?

Comment: There's no magic in any SQL language that will be able to parse an address reliably 100% of the time. In fact there are multiple software packages designed to do exactly this and, even at the high end at thousands of dollars per seat, still mess up an alarmingly high percentage of the time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your data

```
DECLARE @a TABLE
  (
     dwelling_address VARCHAR(max) NOT NULL
  );

INSERT INTO @a
            (dwelling_address)
VALUES      ('Flat 123 Fake Street'),
            ('48 Bond Street'),
            ('Apartment 234 Lemon Lane');
```

query to get your desired result

```
SELECT dwelling_address,
       LEFT(Substring(dwelling_address, Patindex('%[0-9.-]%', dwelling_address),
            8000),
       Patindex('%[^0-9.-]%', Substring(dwelling_address, Patindex('%[0-9.-]%',
                              dwelling_address
       ), 8000)
                              + 'X') - 1) as Outcome_Desired
FROM   @a
```

Comment: Thanks for your comments and code guys, this has been very helpful.

Answer (score 4):

It appears from your sample data you just want to extract the numeric digits.

The most performant way I've found to do this in SQL Server is a combination of *translate* and *replace*.

```
with d as (
  select * from
  (values ('Flat 123 Fake Street'),('48 Bond Street'),('Apartment 234 Lemon Lane'))v(Address)
)
select *, 
 Outcome = Replace(Translate(Address,'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ',Replicate(' ',26)), ' ','')
from d;
```

Add any other required punctuation to the string and increment `26` accordingly.

In production it can be implemented as a table-valued function.

Comment: Nice use of translate.... Still not in the habit of considering it.  +1

Comment: Recently replaced a scalar function that was looping over a string character by character to extract only the digits (think phone number free text entry that allows names or notes to be included) - using this method was 10x faster on average, very useful when used against a table of 5 million customers!

Answer (score 2):

Parsing Addresses can be risky, you may want to consider [Address standardization within a database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41249742/address-standardization-within-a-database/41249971#41249971)

That said, with a bit of string manipulation and the use of CROSS APPLY (or two)

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable Table ([Dwelling Address] varchar(50))  Insert Into @YourTable Values 
 ('Flat 123 Fake Street')
,('48 Bond Street')
,('Apartment 234 Lemon Lane')
,('Flat 1 12 Long Street')
,('No Number')
 
Select A.*
      ,NewValue = substring(S1,1,patindex('%[a-z]%',S1+'a')-1)
 From @YourTable A
 Cross Apply ( values (patindex('%[0-9]%',[Dwelling Address])) )B(P1)
 Cross Apply ( values (stuff([Dwelling Address],1,P1-1,'')   ) )C(S1)
```

**Results**

```
Dwelling Address            NewValue
Flat 123 Fake Street        123 
48 Bond Street              48 
Apartment 234 Lemon Lane    234 
Flat 1 12 Long Street       1 12 
No Number                   NULL
```