# Split full address to contain only street name

Tags: sql, sql-server, string-matching, street-address

I have a table with address1, city, state, and postal code. However, some address1 will also contains city, state and postal code (separated by either comma or space or both).  Example:

```
Address1: 9999 western Rd, Los Angeles, CA, 90001
City: Los Angeles
State: CA
Postal: 90001
I want Address1 to be: 9999 western Rd
```

I've tried the following SQL to fix those addresses: (To simplify here I assume all fields are not null or empty, in the real system for countries without states it will be either empty or same as the country name.)

```
SELECT LEFT(address1, PATINDEX('%[, ]'+city+'%', billingAddress) - 1)
FROM addresses
WHERE address1 like '%[, ]'+city+'%'+state+'%'+postal_code+'%'
    AND PATINDEX('%[, ]'+City+'%', address1) < 12
```

The problem here is many street names include the city they are in. For example, with `9999 KIRKLAND WAY` in city `KIRKLAND`, this query will cause the remaining street name from this query to be `9999`.

Is there anyway to solve this problem in SQL?

Comment: There is no flawless system. Your best option is extracting the zipcode and then doing an address lookup to a (likely paid for) API to get the data split up as required.

Comment: This is a Slippery Slope.  That said, I default to Google's API to format addresses.  Take a peek at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41249742/address-standardization-within-a-database/41249971#41249971

Comment: I've tried FedEx address validation but it is too inconsistence when the address is outside US.

Comment: Oh, you have addresses *outside* of the USA too? Then what "state" do you expect for countries that aren't the United **State**s of America, and don't have *states*? You're in for an even bigger can of worms now.

Comment: With country without states it will be empty or same as their country name. I didn't include it in the question because I think it won't effect the solution. I've edit it into the question now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I will agree with other comments that there is no flawless system - working with addresses can be a giant pain. That being said...

If your Address1 values are sanitized enough to only use commas to separate the various address parts, you might try using [string_split](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) to break it apart and then filter out all but the street information. If it's not that clean, maybe this can at least be a starting point. And this definitely doesn't comprehensively cover international information or any other weirdness that may crop up.

The fiddle example provided below uses some dummy addresses where I've overpopulated a few of the Address1 values and then filter them down to streets with string_split.

[SQL Fiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/eaa29/1)

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[addresses](
    [Address1] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [City] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [State] [char](2) NULL,
    [Postal] [varchar](20) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
GO
INSERT [dbo].[addresses] ([Address1], [City], [State], [Postal]) VALUES (N'204 Cowley Avenue', N'Corpus Christi', N'FL', N'94075-8586')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[addresses] ([Address1], [City], [State], [Postal]) VALUES (N'273 Green Milton Road', N'Albuquerque', N'ND', N'46038-4384')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[addresses] ([Address1], [City], [State], [Postal]) VALUES (N'662 Clarendon Street', N'Detroit', N'RI', N'27706-7936')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[addresses] ([Address1], [City], [State], [Postal]) VALUES (N'57 Oak Boulevard', N'St. Petersburg', N'UT', N'25607-1143')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[addresses] ([Address1], [City], [State], [Postal]) VALUES (N'53 South Rocky Fabien Blvd., Des Moines, IL, 53316-8523', N'Des Moines', N'IL', N'53316-8523')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[addresses] ([Address1], [City], [State], [Postal]) VALUES (N'38 Shreveport Way, Shreveport, NC, 72394-4783', N'Shreveport', N'NC', N'72394-4783')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[addresses] ([Address1], [City], [State], [Postal]) VALUES (N'938 South First Road', N'Arlington', N'MN', N'83467-8269')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[addresses] ([Address1], [City], [State], [Postal]) VALUES (N'674 South Cowley Avenue, Grand Rapids, KY, 51374-4173', N'Grand Rapids', N'KY', N'51374-4173')
GO

SELECT 
    LTRIM(RTRIM(t.value)) AS fixedAddress1,
    a.* from addresses a
CROSS APPLY string_split(a.Address1, ',') t
WHERE LTRIM(RTRIM(t.value)) <> a.City
    AND LTRIM(RTRIM(t.value)) <> a.State
    AND LTRIM(RTRIM(t.value)) <> a.Postal
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the help, this solution is clean! Its not sanitized enough and commonly separated by space, but this could at least solve part of the problem!